# Как растянуть Entry на всю строку Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется фрейм состоящий из кнопки и текстового поля. Подскажите как растянуть текстовое поле на всю строку разместив слева от него кнопку.

```
class f(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.text_field = Entry()
        self.text_field.grid(row=0, column= 1, pady=5,
                             columnspan=9, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.file_dialog = Button(text='Select Folder',
                                  command=self.select_dir)
        self.file_dialog.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    def select_dir(self):
        path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.text_field.insert(0,path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Менеджер компоновки `grid` здесь явно избыточен, хватит и обычного `pack`:

```
self.text_field = Entry()
self.text_field.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=X, expand=True)
self.file_dialog = Button(text='Select Folder', command=self.select_dir)
self.file_dialog.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=(0, 5))
```